# cmake link to macOS pre-compiled binaries at custom path

Tags: cmake, glfw

I want to link to the GLFW library using the binaries provided when downloading from the website at a custom path in my project:

```
include_directories(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR/third_party/glfw/lib-arm64)

add_executable(rpg main.cpp)
target_include_directories(rpg PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/glad/include ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third_party/glfw/include)

find_library(GLFW_LIB NAMES glfw3 PATHS PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR/third_party/glfw PATH_SUFFIXES lib-arm64 lib-universal lib-x86_64)
target_link_libraries(rpg PRIVATE ${GLFW_LIB})
```

I've tried finding both `glfw` and `glfw3` but this fails to find the GLFW library:

```
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
GLFW_LIB
    linked by target "rpg" in directory /Users/ashley/Personal/rpg/src
```

How should I specify the path to link to these rather than use a globally installed version or building from source myself?

**Edit**

Correcting the use of `find_library` as per @Tsyvarev suggestion solved this. The prior update to say it still didn't work was in haste - I wasn't correctly expanding the path variable.

Comment: The first argument to [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) specifies the **variable** which will contain the path to the library after the call. This variable (in form of `${var-name}`) should be used in `target_link_libraries` call. E.g. if you call `find_library(GLFW_LIBRARY NAMES glfw3 PATHS ...)` then you would use `${GLFW_LIBRARY}` for link.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with correct usage of `find_library` as I'm getting a `NOTFOUND` error now.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, that's fixed my issue. If you'd like to put that as an answer I can set it as the accepted solution.

Comment: I don't find useful an answer which just fixes a **typo**. In you updated question you forgot to dereference (with `${}`) the variable `PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR` when use it in PATHS option.